# Collect doesn't work when I ask it to collect in terms of powers of $x-2$

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I want to collect terms in simple polynomial.

First I evaluate

```
Normal[Series[Sin[x], {x, 2, 7}]]
```

which gives

> ```
> (-2 + x) Cos[2] -1/6 (-2 + x)^3 Cos[2] + 1/120 (-2 + x)^5 Cos[2] -((-2 + x)^7 Cos[2])/5040 + Sin[2] - 1/2 (-2 + x)^2 Sin[2] + 1/24 (-2 + x)^4 Sin[2] -1/720 (-2 + x)^6 Sin[2]
> ```

Then I try expand the above which gives

> ```
> -((286 Cos[2])/315) - 19/45 x Cos[2] + 7/15 x^2 Cos[2] + 1/18 x^3 Cos[2] - 1/36 x^4 Cos[2] - 1/120 x^5 Cos[2] + 1/360 x^6 Cos[2] - (x^7 Cos[2])/5040 - (19 Sin[2])/45 + 14/15 x Sin[2] + 1/6 x^2 Sin[2] - 1/9 x^3 Sin[2] - 1/24 x^4 Sin[2] + 1/60 x^5 Sin[2] - 1/720 x^6 Sin[2]
> ```

and I try to reverse the process to collect in power of x-2

```
Collect[
  -((286 Cos[2])/315) - 19/45 x Cos[2] + 7/15 x^2 Cos[2] + 1/18 x^3 Cos[2] - 1/36 x^4 Cos[2] - 1/120 x^5 Cos[2] + 1/360 x^6 Cos[2] - (x^7 Cos[2])/5040 - (19 Sin[2])/45 + 14/15 x Sin[2] + 1/6 x^2 Sin[2] - 1/9 x^3 Sin[2] - 1/24 x^4 Sin[2] + 1/60 x^5 Sin[2] - 1/720 x^6 Sin[2], 
  (-2 + x)]
```

which gives

> ```
> -((286 Cos[2])/315) - 19/45 x Cos[2] + 7/15 x^2 Cos[2] + 1/18 x^3 Cos[2] - 1/36 x^4 Cos[2] - 1/120 x^5 Cos[2] + 1/360 x^6 Cos[2] - (x^7 Cos[2])/5040 - (19 Sin[2])/45 + 14/15 x Sin[2] + 1/6 x^2 Sin[2] - 1/9 x^3 Sin[2] - 1/24 x^4 Sin[2] + 1/60 x^5 Sin[2] - 1/720 x^6 Sin[2]
> ```

Why  doesn't `Collect` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
poly = Normal[Series[Sin[x], {x, 2, 7}]];

polye = poly // Expand;

poly2 = Collect[polye /. x -> y + 2, y] /. y -> x - 2;
```

Verifying that `poly2` is identical to ([`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html)) `poly`

```
poly2 === poly

(* True *)
```

Comment: I try to collect a two point series taylor xE for Cos[x] in x=2,-2 `2/315-(2 x^2)/315+x^4/420-x^6/2520+x^8/40320+Cos[2]/4+7/16 x^2 Cos[2]-5/64 x^4 Cos[2]+1/256 x^6 Cos[2]+(29 Sin[2])/24-11/32 x^2 Sin[2]+1/128 x^4 Sin[2]+(x^6 Sin[2])/1536` and to collect in term (x-2) (x+2) Thanks Bob Hanlon

Comment: @capea -  I don't understand what you are asking. Recommend that you open a new question and provide sufficient detail to make it clearer what you are asking, what you have tried, and what problems you are having.